# Are Online First articles considered "In Press"?

Tags: publications

I'm a little bit confused about this point. If an article has appeared as an Online First article for a print journal, is it still considered "In Press" or is it considered published, and so no longer "In Press"? Or is it only articles that have not cleared the Production Stage yet that are considered "In Press"?

I'm thinking some journals take ages to assign an issue number to accepted articles, so they might stay on the journal website for quite a while until they have one. Some funders want you to attach publications to the grant application that are "In Press", but not "fully" published publications.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I would guess that anything that has been formally accepted (final form) by a publisher is "In Press". Not, of course, for things you put online yourself. And, maybe not, if the online version is a preprint, rather than the final version.

Comment: Yes, to clarify: I meant put online by the journal after acceptance - is that considered "In Press" or something like "published"?

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is, online first articles are completely published except for the fact they aren't assigned to an issue. There's literally no production work left. They will also have a DOI. Therefore, although you can't give the full reference yet, you can list it in the application giving the journal name & DOI.